# Como ignorar entrada de números negativos em Python

Tags: python

Bom, sou iniciante em python e estou aprendendo sobre repetições (while e for), tenho que fazer um programa que leia 10 números inteiros positivos e de a média disso, ignorando negativos. a primeira parte não é complicada, mas, não achei uma forma de impedir a entrada de números negativos pelo usuário, tentei o seguinte código:

```
A = 1
M = 0
X = 0

print('Iremos calcular a media de 10 numéros que voce digitar')

while A <= 10:
    X += int(input(f'Digite o {A}º numero:'))
    while X < 0:
        X = X-X
        break
    A = A + 1
media = X / 10
print(f'a media de {X} é {media}')
```

mas acaba não recuso a entrada de números negativos, e sim, quando é digitado um numero negativo, eu zero minha variável X

Comment: Bom, vc faz `X - X`, e subtrair um número dele mesmo sempre será zero. Em vez de somar toda hora para depois tentar subtrair, o certo seria primeiro verificar se o número é negativo, e só atualizar a soma se não for. Algo assim: https://ideone.com/moMEim

Answer (score -1):

Tens que guardar o input numa variável e só adicionas esse valor se for maior ou igual que zero.

```
    n = int(input(f'Digite o {A}º numero:'))
    if n >= 0:
        X += n
    A = A + 1
```